# Ошибка с админкой на Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pycharm

Делаю свой сайт, сделал модулю добавляю в админку и получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 475, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 51, in check_admin_app
    errors.extend(site.check(app_configs))
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 96, in check
    if modeladmin.model._meta.app_config in app_configs:
AttributeError: 'Comment' object has no attribute 'model'
```

вот мой код в моделях:

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class News(models.Model):
    news_title = models.CharField("название новости", max_length=200)
    news_text = models.TextField("текст новости")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('дата публикации')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.news_title

    def wpr(self):
        return self.pub_date >= (timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30))



class Comment(models.Model):
    news = models.ForeignKey(News, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment_author = models.CharField("Имя автора", max_length=50)
    comment_text = models.TextField("текст комментария")
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField('дата публикации')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment_author
```

вот мой код в админке:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import News, Comment


admin.site.register(News, Comment)
```

Буду благодарен если поможете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте раздельно:

`admin.py`

```
admin.site.register(News)
admin.site.register(Comment)
```